# Information and change management of package.json vs package-lock.json in Node apps

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json, package-lock.json

**Please note:** there are many *similar* questions here however I do believe I am truly asking a new + unique question.

---

I am new to Node and JavaScript and I am trying to understand the different uses of `package.json` and `package-lock.json`. **Before you read any further**, *no*, I am not merely just asking for a summary of what their difference is here.

After doing some homework, my understanding of them is as follows:

- you want to commit *both* to source control, so neither should be mentioned in the `.gitignore`
- `package.json` describes your project and can do some lightweight dependency management, for instance, specifying that you want the latest version of the `fizzbuzz` package, or you want the latest `3.10.x` version of the `fizzbuzz` package
- `package-lock.json` is purely for dependency management and goes into detail about which *specific* dependencies your project should use; for instance if you specify you want the latest `3.10.x` version of `fizzbuzz` in your `package.json` file, the `package-lock.json` file might specify `fizzbuzz-3.10.24`, etc.
- you **do** directly modify/edit your `package.json` file, but you only let NPM and perhaps other command line tools modify your `package-lock.json` (hence no human being should ever edit `package-lock.json`)

Are these statements correct? If not, can someone please provide some details as to how/where my understanding is going awry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Small answer***

Your understanding is correct.

To run a basic Nodejs project you only need `package.json` file on your project, I mean it's required.

The `package.json` is used to keep the dependencies of the project. Which also defines project properties like description, author, license information, scripts, etc.

The `package-lock.json` is used to keep dependencies in a specific version number. It records the exact version of each installed package which allows you to install the same version of packages on different environments.

***Brief answer***

**Why `package-lock.json` is created?**

When you install a package in your project using the below command. for example

`npm install node-sass --save`

, it will install the exact latest version of that package in your project and save the dependency in the `package.json` with a carat (^) sign.

`"node-sass": "^6.0.0"`

Carat (^) means it will support any higher version with the major version. Here, `package-lock.json` is created for locking the dependency with the installed version, in this case 6.

**What is the use of package-lock.json?**

As mentioned above it records the exact version of each installed package which allows you to re-install them. This allows you to generate the same results in different environments. For that, we should use the `package-lock.json` file to install dependencies.

**Why should we commit `package-lock.json` with our project source code (to Git)?**

During deployment, when you run `npm i` (or `npm install`) on your server or whatever environment with the same `package.json` file without the `package-lock.json`, the installed packages might have a higher version now from what you had intended. In that case, if your code targeted a specific version of some of those packages you might have a problem.

**References**

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-lock-json